# I have installed Ubuntu using Crouton why is my / folder a /dev/mmcblk volume and not /dev/sda

Tags: linux, chrome-os

I have 2 chromebooks, an older (2014) model and a newer Acer R11 Touchscreen with N3160 one.

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 (Codenamed Trusty) on my newer chrome book. I open GParted and I see 3 devices

- `/dev/mmcblk0` (32 Gb chrome os / Ubuntu 14.04 Root mount point Ubuntu)
- `/dev/mmcblk1` (64 Gb Storage Micro Sd card Chrome os / Ubuntu)
- `/dev/sda` (4 Gb flash drive for transfering files Chrome os / Ubuntu

My question is why is the internal storage on my newer chrome book coming up as a `/dev/mmcblk` volume when I don't see this on my older one? Does this mean that there is an SD card for internal Storage? If so why is my USB flash drive showing up as a `/dev/sda` volume? Is there a true SSD chip in there?  If there is emmc flash in the chrome book why were the root volumes /dev/sda in my old chrome book?

If this was confusing, Sorry. I am confused as to why my chrome book is acting this way.

Thanks, 9291Sam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/dev/mmcblk*` devices are native SD Cards. USB devices and SATA disks are represented as `/dev/sd*` devices. I'm not sure what else you're asking.

Comment: You still did not answer why it was like this in my old chrome book

Comment: @9291Sam because when I answered your question you hadn't included any mention of a second Chromebook.

Answer (score 1):

A modern chromebook typically has 16GB or 32GB of internal storage using an [eMMC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MultiMediaCard) device. This is [partitioned](https://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/chromiumos-design-docs/disk-format) into 12 partitions, to provided 3 root partitions (only 2 used), 3 kernels (only 2 used) etc.

Comment: You did but answer why it was like this in my old chrome book

Comment: @9291Sam How old is old? The linked article shows you that the eMMC devices is a multimedia card, just like an SD card, so shows up as an mmcblk device. Some older chromebooks have real SATA hard drives in them instead of eMMC chips.

Comment: Ok now I under stand this my old (2014.) chrome book has a real ssd in it and the new one only has a emmc flash in it. Thanks for the help

Comment: @9291Sam It is all about cost, eMMC is cheaper than an SSD. As a rule of thumb the cost of the components of anything electrical is 10 to 20% of retail. So a $250 chromebook has $25 to $50 of components in it. For that you get a keyboard, screen, cpu, memory, wifi chip, tpm, embedded controller, trackpad, speakers, motherboard, hdmi connector, couple of USB connectors, SD connector, boot flash x2, and the internal storage. Saving a few cents on each of these can make a big difference to the bottom line. The market for chromebooks in the US was 7m in the US in 2015 according to Gartner.